# Почему конструкторы в типах не занимают место?

Tags: c++, указатели, конструктор, структуры-данных

Есть структура:

```
struct tube
{
  char var1;
  int var2;
  char var3;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(tube);
}
```

Она имеет фиксированный размер. Почему когда я добавляю методы к этой структуре:

```
#include <iostream>

struct tube
{
  char var1;
  int var2;
  char var3;

  tube()
  {
      var1 = 0x00;
      var2 = 0x04030201;
      var2 = 0x05;      
  }

  void A(){

  }

};

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(tube);
}
```

ее размер не меняется? Разве структура внутри себя не хранит указатели, занимающие ее память, на свои методы?

Comment: Нет, это же не javascript какой-нибудь

Comment: А **зачем**? Код-то один и тот же, и для невиртуальных функций достаточно знать адрес, как для любой обычной функции. Для виртуальных - все адреса хранятся в таблице для класса, т.е. одной для всех объектов, и размер объекта вырастает на один указатель. Это не оговорено в стандарте, но это самая распространенная (если не единственная :)) реализация...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Действительно указателей на методы внутри структуры не хранится.

Каждый метод объявенный внутри структуры по сути (и в ассемблерном коде после компиляции) является функцией, первый аргумент которой -- адрес экземпляра этой структуры.

Код

```
struct foo
{
  int bar;

  int baz() { return bar * bar; }
}
```

По сути эквивалентен

```
struct foo
{
  int bar;
}

int baz(foo *f) { return f->bar * f->bar; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Невиртуальные методы класса - это просто обычные посторонние функции со скрытым параметром `this`. На низком уровне никакого отношения к классу они не имеют и на размер класса никак не влияют.

Почему вы решили, что в классе должны храниться какие-то "указатели" на такие методы - не ясно.